# Генерация сущностей в Doctrine 2 | Подключение к БД

Tags: php, doctrine2, zend-framework-2

Здравствуйте, 
У меня не получается сгенерировать сущности по уже имеющейся Базе Данных. Или же подключится к ней...
Я имею ZendFramework 2, Doctrine. 
При этом, подключение проходит успешно, хотя... Я не уверен ибо еще не совсем разобрался в механизме подключение к БД через доктрину.
И по ТулБару видно, что подключение удалось, ошибок нет.
Но при попытке создать сущность, через команду:

```
call doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping annotation module/Application/src/ --namespace="Application\Entity\\" --from-database
```

И в итоге получаю:
http://prntscr.com/d8cxd2
Скажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема и как её решить...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не установлен драйвер PDO. Включить его можно в php.ini

Возможно драйвер работает для веб, но не подключен для консольной версии.
Посмотреть какой php.ini используется у вас в консоли можно командой

```
php --ini
```

Comment: Спасибо)
Да так и есть.
Нужно было просто это всё делать на локальном сервере и перенести уже на глобальный)